# Add variables in an loop to a formula

Tags: python

I have a problem.
I am using a formula:

```
x = var1 * multiplier1 + var2 * multiplier2, etc.
```

I have 300 variables, so I want to loop through the variables and add them, but what I try doesn't work. I understand why it is not working, but I can't figure out how I have to do it correctly. This is my code:

```
multiplier = {}
count = 0

while (count != len(data[0])):

   ri = np.random.randint(len(data))
   point = data[ri]

   x = point[count] * multiplier[count]
   count += 1
```

It is not adding the variables to the formula, but it calculates it again. How can I make it work?

Comment: The `for` statement would make your code much clearer than the `while`

Comment: Knowing how `data` looks like would help.

Comment: Its a pretty long code to show the data, but it's an 2D Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing a `+` sign.
Change `x = point[count] * multiplier[count]`
to `x += point[count] * multiplier[count]`
And declare `x=0` before your loop.

Beware that nowhere in this code the multiplier dict is populated with values !

```
multiplier = {}
count = 0
x = 0

while (count != len(data[0])):

   ri = np.random.randint(len(data))
   point = data[ri]

   x += int(point[count]) * multiplier[count]
   count += 1
```

Comment: as you where doing `+`/`*` operations I assumed that your data were numbers. It appears that they are string. Edited my answer to convert the `str` to `int`